# ImagePickerController with cameraOverlayView not adding to the ViewController's View

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller, camera-overlay

I'm trying to present an `UIImagePickerController` with an Overlay view on it.I'm adding `OverlayViewController's` view as a subview to `ViewController`. But When I dump the app into device it is showing a Blank Screen.

**My Code is here:**

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) OverlayViewController *overlayViewController;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
[super viewDidLoad];

self.overlayViewController =
[[[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OverlayViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

// as a delegate we will be notified when pictures are taken and when to dismiss the image picker
self.overlayViewController.delegate = self;

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    [self.overlayViewController setupImagePicker:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentModalViewController:self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES];
}

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

OverlayViewController.m

```
@interface OverlayViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Capture;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Library;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *ZoomOut;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *FrontCam;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *zoom;

@end

@implementation OverlayViewController
@synthesize delegate;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

    self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;

}
return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{

[_imagePickerController release];

[super dealloc];
}

- (void)setupImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;

if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
{
    // user wants to use the camera interface
    //
    self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

    if ([[self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView subviews] count] == 0)
    {
        // setup our custom overlay view for the camera
        //
        // ensure that our custom view's frame fits within the parent frame
       CGRect overlayViewFrame = self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;

        NSLog(@"Overlay view Frame heidgt is %f and width is %f", self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame.size.height,self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame.size.width);


        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 320.0, 480.0);

        NSLog(@"Overlay view Frame heidgt is %f and width is %f", self.view.frame.size.height,self.view.frame.size.width);

        self.view.frame = newFrame;

        [self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];

    }
}
}
```

I have downloaded Sample Code from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196 to do this.

I want to present a custom view with some controls(Capture button, flash button... etc.) on it. How can i achieve this..?

Answer (score 0):

Just place

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.opaque = NO;
```

in the `initWithFrame` method of your `overlayView`, and use it:

```
CGRect crossFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2.0-50, self.view.bounds.size.height/2.0-50, 100, 100);
UIView *crosshairView = [[BNRCameraCrosshair alloc]initWithFrame:crossFrame];
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = crosshairView;
```